# Optimising regexp search telephone # search results (JS)?

Tags: javascript, json, regex

---

I am writting software for my 2nd year project which allows me to extract telephone numbers from a website using JSON. The code I have written extracts the contents of the website in HTML format and within "". Is there any way I can identify the telephone number by writing some type of script using JavaScript?

---

For example: Currently would receive: +44 (0)1484 432911.

---

Which means there is no way I can identify what number it is but I want to receive: John: +44 (0)1484 432911. Or General Information: +44 (0)1484 432911.

Comment: you might link to a post on regex101.com  with your current pattern and a sample of what your searching in.

Comment: What line of code should I be adding? Or can anyone explain the logic how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the formated phone number across the site you can match it like this:

```
new RegExp(/(\w:)?(\s)?\+[\d]{2}\s[\(\d\)][\d]+/ig).test("John: +44 (0)1484 432911")
```

it will also work without the name because the first part is optional `(\w:)?(\s)?`

if the phone numbers are not in the same format you should define a pattern and examine the regex.